# How to convert React.FC syntax to const x = () => {}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this code below that I tried to convert its syntax (I am using TypeScript, React) from the syntax below to `const x = () => {}` form.

```
const EntryDetails: FC<{ entry: Entry }> = ({ entry }) => {
  switch (entry.type) {
    case 'Hospital':
      return <HospitalCard entry={entry} />;

    case 'HealthCheck':
      return <HealthCheckCard entry={entry} />;

    default:
      return assertNever(entry);
  }
};
```

Somehow it crashed my code so I assumed I did not convert it properly. Can someone help me get it converted?

My attempt was as below:

```
const EntryDetails = (entry: Entry) => {
  switch (entry.type) {
    case 'Hospital':
      return <HospitalCard entry={entry} />;

    case 'HealthCheck':
      return <HealthCheckCard entry={entry} />;

    default:
      return assertNever(entry);
  }
};
```

and I also tried

```
const EntryDetails = ({entry}: Entry) => {
  switch (entry.type) {
    case 'Hospital':
      return <HospitalCard entry={entry} />;

    case 'HealthCheck':
      return <HealthCheckCard entry={entry} />;

    default:
      return assertNever(entry);
  }
};
```

Comment: You're missing the `=` sign between the name and arrow function.

Comment: Your first example **is** _"`const x = () => {}` form"_. It's an arrow function. What was the problem you were trying to solve? If you're not actually using TypeScript, for example, just remove the type (`: FC<{ entry: Entry }>`).

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: Then it's not clear what you think you need to change about the first example. _Why_ did you try to convert its syntax (and to what, given it's already in the form you say you wanted)?

Comment: The first original code is in form "const EntryDetails: FC<{ entry: Entry }> = ({ entry }) => {}"

Comment: ...so what? That's **still an arrow function**, just with a _type_ (because you're using TypeScript).

Comment: But my attempt to convert it became like this: const EntryDetails = (entry: Entry) => {}
For some reason the code isn't acting the same as the original

Comment: Well why would it? You've changed the _signature_ of the function. You were previously (correctly) _destructuring_ the `entry` out of the `props` argument, now you're trying to claim that's the shape of all of the props.

Answer (score -1):

your function component must look like this...

```
const EntryDetail: FC<PropsFromYourTypesSheet> = (props) => {
  your Code
}
```